# How to extract certain parts of a web page in Python

Tags: python, html, string

Target web page:
http://www.immi.gov.au/skilled/general-skilled-migration/estimated-allocation-times.htm

The section I want to extract:

```
  <tr>
  <td>Skilled &ndash; Independent (Residence) subclass 885<br />online</td>
  <td>N/A</td>
  <td>N/A</td>
  <td>N/A</td>
  <td>15 May 2011</td>
  <td>N/A</td>
  </tr>
```

Once the code finds this section by searching the keyword "**subclass 885
online**", it should then print the date which is within the 5th  tag which is "**15 May 2011**" as shown above.

It's just a monitor for myself to keep an eye on the progress of my immigration application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> "[Beau--ootiful Soo--oop!](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)
>
> [Beau--ootiful Soo--oop!](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)
>
> Soo--oop of the e--e--evening,
>
> [Beautiful, beauti--FUL SOUP!](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)"

--Lewis Carroll, [*Alice's Adventures in Wonderland*](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Ergs/alice-X.html)

I think this is exactly what he had in mind!

The Mock Turtle would probably do something like this:

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> import urllib2
>>> url = 'http://www.immi.gov.au/skilled/general-skilled-migration/estimated-allocation-times.htm'
>>> page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
>>> for row in soup.html.body.findAll('tr'):
...     data = row.findAll('td')
...     if data and 'subclass 885online' in data[0].text:
...         print data[4].text
... 
15 May 2011
```

But I'm not sure it would help, since that date has already passed!

Good luck with the application!

Answer (score 6):

You might want to use this as a starting point:

```
Python 2.6.7 (r267:88850, Jun 13 2011, 22:03:32) 
[GCC 4.6.1 20110608 (prerelease)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib2, re
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> urllib2.urlopen('http://www.immi.gov.au/skilled/general-skilled-migration/estimated-allocation-times.htm')
<addinfourl at 139158380 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x84aa2ac>>
>>> html = _.read()
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> soup.find(text = re.compile('\\bsubclass 885\\b')).parent.parent.find('td', text = re.compile(' [0-9]{4}$'))
u'15 May 2011'
```

Comment: Beginner here, but from what I've read, the preferred module for screen scraping in lxml. Is it just a matter of preference or do either offer any significant advantage? Also, you are off you 30 to 1 ratio.

Comment: Hi Pete, I haven't used lxml, I'll have to look into it. And you're right, I'm off, but in the right direction :^)

Comment: Ah, I thought you wanted to be off in the other direction. Whats wrong with asking questions? D:

Comment: nothing's wrong with asking questions, but by the time I do all the "due diligence" necessary to ask a question properly, I've usually found the answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is a library called Beautiful Soup which does the job you asked for. http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/