# wget wikimedia image?

Tags: bash, shell, wget, wikimedia-commons

I am trying to download an image from Wikimedia Commons by using a URL to a page in the file namespace:

```
wget http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:A_golden_tree_during_the_golden_season.JPG
```

all I get is a JPG file that I cannot open. But when you go to the link you actually see the page instead of the image itself, but there is a link called "Full resolution" that sends you to the real image link which is: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/92/A_golden_tree_during_the_golden_season.JPG

How can I download this file by having only the first link ?

Comment: Why [tag:bash]? You're going to have to do some HTML parsing here. Have you considered using [tag:python], [tag:perl], [tag:clojure]... ?

Comment: Not good at those... :/

Comment: @AltinUkshini: Well, learn. It's not hard to do with Python.

Comment: Agreed. I'd probably do this in [tag:python]. There are lots of examples on this site as to [How to extract certain parts of a web page in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7055382/78845). I've just linked to one that I like.

Comment: Guys I cannot learn a new programming language in a night...

Comment: Do you know any languages (other than [tag:bash])? Perhaps you have a better tool in your toolbox for this job.

Comment: You do not need HTML parsing nor should you to it to accomplish this task. See my reply below.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
wget http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:A_golden_tree_during_the_golden_season.JPG -O output.html; wget $(cat output.html | grep fullMedia | sed 's/\(.*href="\/\/\)\([^ ]*\)\(" class.*\)/\2/g')
```

The first `wget` fetches the link you specify. I browsed few pages and found that high resolution images were under `div` with class=fullMedia. It parses the url of the image and then fetches that image.

**PS**: As suggested above, bash is not a neat way of doing this. You should look at something that parses dom trees.

Comment: +1: You deserve some reputation points for your research effort.

Comment: The output of action=view of index.php (here both is implicitly used through rewrite rules and MediaWiki defaults) depends on various factors and may change unexpectedly at any time. Do not rely on that. Either use the [API](http://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url&titles=File:A_golden_tree_during_the_golden_season.JPG) or extract the title without namespace and pass it to [[Special:Redirect]] as I suggested in my reply below.

Answer (score 2):

Extract the title without namespace (`A_golden_tree_during_the_golden_season.JPG`) and pass it to [Special:Redirect](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special%3aRedirect).

```
wget http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:Redirect/file/$( echo 'http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:A_golden_tree_during_the_golden_season.JPG' | sed 's/.*\/File\:\(.*\)/\1/g' )
```

Answer (score 0):

wget http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/92/A_golden_tree_during_the_golden_season.JPG

You were fetching the web page not the image itself.

Comment: That seems to be understood in the question.

Comment: yes I know, but I want to get it from the first link...
I have a list of image names that I can do a wget link/File:imagename

But that doesn't work bcs the image I download cannot be opened

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following link to retrive :https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/92/A_golden_tree_during_the_golden_season.JPG
Even I had got the same problem,click on the image you will get the above link ,i hope this helps